# Erro de conversão no c::b

Tags: c

Eu tenho uma fila definida assim:

```
typedef struct nodo
{
   int inf;
   struct nodo *next;
}NODO;

typedef struct
{
   struct nodo *INICIO;
   struct nodo *FIM;
}DESCRITOR;
typedef DESCRITOR *FILA_ENC;
```

E uma função que consulta e retira o primeiro elemento da fila:

```
int cons_ret (FILA_ENC f)
{
    if (eh_vazia(f))
    {
        printf ("retirada em fila vazia");
        exit(5);
    }
    int val=f->INICIO->inf;
    FILA_ENC aux=f->INICIO; /*erro aqui*/
    f->INICIO=f->INICIO->next;
    if (!f->INICIO)
    f->FIM=NULL;
    free(aux);
    return (val);
}
```

Só que ta dando um erro que diz "cannot convert 'NODO* {aka nodo*}' to 'FILA_ENC {aka DESCRITOR*}' in initialization", e não sei o porquê.

Comment: Não seria `FILA_ENC aux = f;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua variável `aux` é do tipo `DESCRITOR *`, já o atributo `f->INICIO` é do tipo `struct nodo*`. São ponteiros para tipos diferentes, você não pode atribuir de um para o outro.